# How to extract actual non-temporary filename from fileInput widget

Tags: shiny

I'm using a fileInput widget in a Rshiny App.  I would like to include the filename from which the record came when I'm compiling the df.

I'm able to extract the temp file name using the `input$inputname$datapath` command, as detailed here:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html

However, I would like to be able to extract the actual file name as it appears on the user's system.  How would I do this?

Comment: isn't that `input$inputname$name`?

Comment: Indeed it is, I should have seen that.  Thanks warmoverflow!  Please answer (instead of a comment) this so that I can mark yours as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Shiny documentation, when a file is uploaded, the `input$inputname` variable becomes a dataframe that contains 4 columns, with one of them being the original file name `input$inputname$name`

http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html

> Whenever a file upload completes, the corresponding input variable is
>   set to a dataframe. This dataframe contains one row for each selected
>   file, and the following columns:
>
> **name**
>       The filename provided by the web browser. This is not the path to read to get at the actual data that was uploaded (see datapath
>   column).
>
> **size**
>       The size of the uploaded data, in bytes.
>
> **type**
>       The MIME type reported by the browser (for example, text/plain), or empty string if the browser didn't know.
>
> **datapath**
>       The path to a temp file that contains the data that was uploaded. This file may be deleted if the user performs another upload
>   operation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as best as I can tell, Shiny is not designed to store original filename values. That being said, you can use another library such as "shinyFiles" (the function you need is shinyFileChoose). You can find their documentation at: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyFiles/shinyFiles.pdf